# MVVM WPF replace ListBox with Label when ItemsSource is empty or null

Tags: wpf, collections, mvvm, visibility

I have this line in WPF (.NET 3.5) :

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Locks}" Style="{DynamicResource FancyListBox}" />
```

My desired behavior is that when the property Locks (an ObservableCollection) is either null or contains 0 elements, show a label like the one below instead of the ListBox.

```
<Label Content="No locks are present" Style="{DynamicResource FancyLabel}" />
```

The only solution I can think of so far is to bind the Locks property to visibility using a valueconverter (i.e. converters like CollectionToVisibilityShowIfNull, CollectionToVisibilityShowIfNotNull), but I am not sure if that is the best solution.

```
... Visibility={Binding Locks, Converter={StaticResource CollectiontoVisibilityShowIfNull}} ..
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I usually do:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="lstLocks" ItemsSource="{Binding Locks}" Style="{DynamicResource FancyListBox}" />
    <Label Name="lblNoLocks" Content="No locks are present" Style="{DynamicResource FancyLabel}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
</Grid>

...
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Locks.Count}" Value="0">
    <Setter TargetName="lstLocks" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    <Setter TargetName="lblNoLocks" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this was happening in a datatemplate so I wasn't sure if using Name would work, but it did!  Thanks you Thomas

Comment: boo, not available for WP7 :(

Comment: Where are you even supposed to add DataTrigger? Window.Triggers wants EventTriggers.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan, you can add it in a DataTemplate, or in a Style, depending on the situation. But now I tend to add a specific property in the ViewModel and bind the visibility to it, with a BooleanToVisibilityConverter